# Send graph values to Chart.js template with Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, chart.js

I'm trying to make a data visualizer with a Flask and Chart.js api. My application has the following structure:

- API

  - api.py
  - templates

    - index.html
  - static

    - css

      - estil.css
    - js

      - chartjs.js
        (...)

So my idea is to put all the charts in the same file, outside the html. My problem is that I don't know how to send the data that I read from the database with Flask to the chart.js template. Surely it is very easy, but it is the first time that I touch chart.js and javascript and it is resisting me a bit.

(**PSEODUCODE**)

Python flask api (api.py):

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    fruits = []
    # SQLITE3 QUERY
    return render_template("index.html", fruits = fruits)
```

HTML (index.html):

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="static/js/chartjs.js"
```

JS (chartjs.js):

```
const ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart');
const background_color2 = ['#33a3ec', '#ff6384'];

new Chart(ctx2, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ['Orange', 'Pineaple'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [82, 38],
            /*
             * If I put it inside the HTML with <script>TODO</script>
             * it works fine for me but if I do it here it doesn't show
             * me the graphics:
             * data: {% values %},
             */
            backgroundColor: background_color2,
            borderWidth: 10,
            borderColor: "#fbfbfb"
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            display: false
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000,
            animateRotate: true,
            render: false
        },
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Juice fruits"
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have seen that I have a negative vote, but they have not given me a comment about why the negative vote. Could someone tell me what I did wrong to rephrase the question correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, after not coding for a few hours comes the answer. It occurred to me to create each graph inside a function (like this):

```
function chartFruitJuice(fruits) {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    const background_color = ['#33a3ec', '#ffce55', '#4ac1c1', '#ff00ff00'];
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Pineaple'],
            datasets: [{
                data: fruits,
                backgroundColor: background_color,
                borderWidth: 10,
                borderColor: "#fbfbfb"
            }]
        }, options: {
            scales: {
                display: false
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 1000,
                animateRotate: true,
                render: false
            },
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    display: true,
                    align: 'bottom',
                    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
                    borderRadius: 3,
                    font: {
                        size: 18,
                    },
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Fruit juice"
                },
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And in the HTML, pass the Flask values as parameters of said function:

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script>
    charFruitJuice({{ fruits | tojson | safe }});
</script>
```